# How can I combine a variable name when export a new variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

Say I have a for loop:

```
for z in {0..11}
do
export jbod$z=`grep "Firmware state" driveinfo-$z | awk 'BEGIN{FS=":";} {print $2}'`
done
```

How can I get the new variable i'm trying to export to include the number from the loop?
For each pass of the loop I want a variable like so: jbod1=string jbod2=string jbod3=string

I should also mention if I echo $jbod$z it doesn't work...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for setting the variables already works. You're just reading the value incorrectly.

Try `echo $jbod4` and you'll see that they're set.

To access variables dynamically, you can use indirection:

```
z=4
name="jbod$z"
echo "$name is set to ${!name}"
```

Comment: It shouldn't work, he needs eval or declare as @anubhava pointed. Try this: `for i in {1..3}; do a$i=$i; done; echo "$a1 $a2 $a3"`

Comment: @Tiago That's not what OP does. OP uses export, and `export a$i=$i` works fine.

Comment: Didn't know export would work. Thanks +1 for that :)